# adding a django format to messages

Tags: python, django, message

i am trying to add to my messages.success the username so when he login the message go up and have the username
views.py:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        if username and password:

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            
            if user is not None:
                l_login(request, user)
                success_url = '/home'
                messages.success(request, 'You logged in to ')
                return redirect('home') 
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Username or Password is Incorrect')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Fill out all the Fields Please')  
    
    return render(request, 'register/login.html',{})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain this from the user object:

```
messages.success(request, f'You logged in to {user.username}')
```

The `f'…'` is [*literal string interpolation* [pep-498]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

Comment: you know how to make the display delayed??

Comment: @YusofAntar: what do you mean with "*delayed*"?

Comment: the message appear for ever and dosn't hide after a moment

Comment: @YusofAntar: you should look for some css/js for example to do this:  https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/mdbootstrap/944829